# Understanding type families

Tags: haskell, type-families

I am learning Type Families and trying to understand why I am not getting a compile-time error under a specific case.

My type family is defined as below:

```
type family Typ a b :: Constraint
type instance Typ (Label x) (Label y) = ()
```

I have two functions as below:

```
func1 :: (Typ (Label "la") (Label "lb")) => Label "la" -> Label "lb" -> String
func1  = undefined

func2 :: (Typ (Label "la") String) => Label "la" -> String -> String
func2  = undefined
```

Both these functions compile OK.

When I try to view the type of `func1`, I get the correct signature. But, when I try to view the type of `func2`, I get the error the following error

> Could not deduce (Typ (Label "la") String)

Why is this so? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: My assumption is that it is because there is an instance declared for `Typ (Label x) (Label y)` but not for `Typ (Label x) String`. What is the definition of `Label`?

Comment: `data Label (l :: Symbol) = Get` I was hoping to get a compile-time error for `func2`, and not a runtime error

Comment: You may be interested in [this discussion of context reduction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-910004.5.3). I'm tempted to call it a bug that ghci complains: it probably should not be doing context reduction on user-supplied type signatures. Note that of course if you ever tried to use `func2` in a real program -- which would eventually trace back to a `main` which has no context, and in particular would not be allowed to have `Typ (Label "la") String` in its context -- you would get a type error.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks. Let me read through the context reduction details.

Comment: This is an open type family, so someone could later come along and add a `type instance Type (Label x) String = ()` in a module that imports this module. A closed type family would disallow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to duplicate what you described with this definition of `Label`:

```
import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)

data Label (a :: Symbol)
```

And adding:

```
type instance Typ (Label x) String = ()
```

Then provides the type of `func2`

**Edit**

Sorry I misunderstood the concern. My understanding is that checking the satisfiability of the constraint will be deferred until `func2` is actually used since an instance could be added later.

For example, adding:

```
func3 = func2 (undefined :: Label "la") ""
```

Causes it to fail at compile time.

The way I make sense of it is that `func2` is saying, if you give me a `Label "la"` and a `String` *and an instance of `Typ (Label "la") String` is in scope at the time*, I'll give you a `String`. But `func2` doesn't need to have an instance in scope to know *what it would do with one if it had it*.

Comment: Yes @DanielWagner . Your understanding is correct. I am interested in why the type error is delayed.

Comment: @PrasannaKRao "Why it is delayed" -- this part is easy. It is a general principle that complaints about unsatisfied constraints are delayed as long as possible, to support separate compilation. (With separate compilation, you may not know all the ways to satisfy a constraint.) But I'm not sure about the "and no farther" part.

Comment: @PrasannaKRao I'm sorry I misunderstood initially and have updated my answer.